Predicting Amount of Precipitate Formation in a Common Ion Effect
Hey Chemistry Community,
I'm currently grappling with a problem in my chemistry studies and could really use some guidance. Here's the scenario: I have 10mL of 0.5 mole hydrochloric acid (HCl) and 5mL of a 6-mole sodium chloride (NaCl) solution. I'm trying to determine if a precipitate will form when these two solutions are mixed and how much precipitate it would form mathematically based on the common ion effect and Le Chatelier's principle.
I tried to just assume that all chlorine from the hydrochloric acid would contribute to the common ion effect, but I'm not sure if this would work.
Cd = diluted concentration of hydrochloric acid (mol/L)
Ci = initial concentration of hydrochloric acid (mol/L)
Vi = initial volume of hydrochloric acid (mL)
Vwater - volume of water added (mL)
VWater = 15mL - 10mL = 5mL
Cd = Ci*Vi / Vi + Vwater
Cd = 0.5*10/10+5 = 0.333M
Moles of HCl after dilution: 0.333M x 15mL = 4.955mmol
Amount of precipitate = 4.955mmol x 58.44 g/mol = 291.91 mg = 0.29291
I'm not sure if this works though.
I also tried calculating through solving for X but I am not sure how to calculate the Ksp:
Ksp = [Na+] x [Cl-]
Ksp = [0.02Na+] x [0.02Cl-]
Ksp = 0.02^2
Ksp = 0.0004
Ksp = [Na-] * [Cl+]
0.0004 mol^2 / L^2 = (x)*(x+0.004)
0.0004 mol^2 / L^2 = x^2 + 0.004x
0 = x^2 + 0.004x - 0.002704
Quadratic Formula
x=0.050038447325031M, -0.054038447325031
0.05 (mol/L) ^ 2  * 58.44
= 2.922 grams of Precipitate
This method gave me more grams than I started off with so it doesn't seem to work. I would just like help understanding how I would go about solving this problem.
My main questions are:
Will a precipitate form in this reaction?
If not, what adjustments can I make to induce precipitate formation without significantly altering the volumes of the solutions?
I've been trying to work through the stoichiometry and solubility rules, but I'm hitting a roadblock. Any insights, explanations, or step-by-step approaches to solve this would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance for your help.

It is not clear at all what you have already done, concerning symbolic equations and explicit quantification.

Hint: How does concentration of Cl- change in your scenario? How it should change to precipitate anything?

Well it should increase to unbalance the equation right? And then the equation would shift to the left?
